# WooCommerce custom quantity available in URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I have a web page with Wordpress and WooCommerce, but the stock (quantity available of each product) I get it in a URL like this (http://www.mystock.com/page.php&id_item=623533&coloritem=68)
I have to put in the link, the SKU (e.g. 623533-68) and I get in return a CVS whit some data

[image]

I need to update (or at least show in memory/in front-end) the real **price_a** and **quantity available**. How can I do that?

**EDIT 1:**
For now I don´t need the code for get the CSV info, for information is:

```
$url = "http://www.mystock.com/page.php&id_item=623533&coloritem=68";
$csv = file_get_contents($url);
$data = str_getcsv($csv);
```

***$data***
 is an array of string, and I can get the info that I need.
But I still don't know what php file of wordpress to change, for show the actual_quantity and the if the customer add in a cart the product, know if quantity is greater than zero.

**EDIT 2:**

In this [page](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productset_stock_quantity/) show the oficial way that update the quantity, whit the function

`$product->set_stock_quantity(SomeFloat);` but doesn't works. `$product` is a new `WC_Product` object. And desn't show any error, just, nothing happen.

Thanks